Add points to WFS Layers with QField
I've been looking into some of the data collection and form options for QField and QGIS, but our data is currently being hosted and displayed in another app. I can pull this data in through a WFS, and I can easily add data points in the desktop version of QGIS. However, I need to be able to use mobile data collection through QField with these WFS layers, but haven't had any luck with this.
I've had no issues collecting data that has been set up in a geopackage, but the WFS layers appear to be locked as read-only and I haven't found any way to change this.
Has anyone found a way to work with this kind of setup, or any alternative solutions from a similar set up?

Most WFS only allow read/query operations; to allow adding/editing of features requires that the WFS has extra  'transactional' capabilities.
